# Facebook Python API: как получить название местоположения пользователя?

Tags: python, facebook-api

Как получить название местоположения пользователя в статистике по объявлению?

У меня следующая функция пока что:

```
def parse_ads_stat(account_id, data):
    
    print('printing data')
    print(f'data: {data}')
    
    stat = dict()
    stat['fb_ad_account'] = [account_id for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['fb_campaign_id'] = [data[i]['campaign_id'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['fb_adset_id'] = [data[i]['adset_id'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['fb_ad_id'] = [data[i]['ad_id'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['fb_spend'] = [str(data[i]['spend']).replace('.', ',') for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['fb_date'] = [data[i]['date_start'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['impressions'] =  [data[i]['impressions'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['clicks'] = [data[i]['clicks'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['reach'] = [data[i]['reach'] for i in range(len(data))]
    stat['location'] = [d.get('location', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
    stat['video_p25_watched_actions'] = [d.get('video_p25_watched_actions', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
    stat['video_p50_watched_actions'] = [d.get('video_p50_watched_actions', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
    stat['video_p75_watched_actions'] = [d.get('video_p75_watched_actions', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
    stat['video_p100_watched_actions'] = [d.get('video_p100_watched_actions', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
    stat['video_play_actions'] = [d.get('video_play_actions', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
    return stat

stat['location'] = [d.get('location', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
```

Здесь пытаюсь получить местоположение, получаю везде "0".

Пробовал и так:

```
stat['location'] = [data[i]['location'] for i in range(len(data))]
```

Но понимаю что последний вариант скорее всего бесполезен, т.к. `data` содержит только следующее:

```
{'ad_id': '23847664832490708', 'campaign_id': '23847664832280708', 'adset_id': '23847664832290708', 'spend': '314.6', 'impressions': '1878', 'clicks': '22', 'reach': '1865', 'date_start': '2021-04-15', 'date_stop': '2021-04-15'}
```

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, почему вы в половине кода обращаетесь к списку так `data[i] for i in range(len(data))`, а во второй половине кода так `for d in data`, это чтобы всех запутать, да? )  Второй вариант проще и понятнее, если вам нужны только элементы с индексом `i`, если что. А вообще у вас список словарей ведь в `data`, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: И да, если в словаре нет `location`, то непонятно, где вам его взять.

Comment: @CrazyElf, в том то и дело, что в словаре нет и video_p25_watched_actions и похожих значений. Но они получаются таким образом:
[d.get('video_p25_watched_actions', [{}])[0].get('value', 0) for d in data]
Видимо это особенность API. Вот я и попробовал location таким же образом получить. Но видимо так нельзя и надо как-то по другому. Вообще изначально скрипт не я писал, пытаюсь разобраться как в него что-то добавить.